Why/When to use passwd -d?
According with man passwd exists the following information:
-d, --delete
 Delete a user's password (make it empty).
 This is a quick way to disable a password for an account.
 It will set the named account passwordless.

For experimental purposes was created a test user as sudo adduser testuser and later was executed the following command:

sudo passwd -d testuser

Therefore the su - testuser works without requesting any password as expected
Just being curious, if this approach exists, is because exists at least one reason to accomplish this approach. Therefore
Question

Why/When to use passwd -d?


Why did the chicken cross the road?  To get to the other side.  Why/when would you use password --delete?  If you want to set an account to be passwordless.  What are you asking?

In other words: Why/When create an account with free access to other users?

Depending on what Linux you are using, passwd -d will have different effects. On some (most?) Linuxes, it lets you log in without a password, while on others, it will disallow using a password for logging in (logging in could still be done via e.g. SSH using an SSH key).  E.g. Ubuntu works one way and Alpine the other. You don't appear to say what Linux you are using.

@Kusalananda Thanks for the feedback. In this case is for Ubuntu. But I wrote here the OP because I know this command exists on Fedora too. So I assumed at a first glance the behavior is the same both OS - remove the password requirement to accomplish a login

There are three ways an account can be "passwordless":

It can have a blank (zero size) hashed password in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow.  In this case, if it is not otherwise prohibited, no password prompt is given after entering the login name.  (This is what passwd -d does)
It can have an invalid hashed password (such as * or !) in which case, no password will work, and password prompt will be shown.  The login prompt would act similarly for an invalid login name.  (Similarly passwd -l actually prepends a ! making it invalid without deleting the hash.)
The hashed password could be set to the hash of the blank password.  In this case, a password prompt will be given, but login will only be allowed if enter is pressed at the prompt without typing anything.  (Literally, the zero size blank password is valid.)

The second case (no valid password) is common for accounts where login is not intended.
The other two cases are rarely (but not never) useful, and in some cases, may be dangerous (as in, security vulnerability).   Network access programs like ssh have options to explicitly prohibit logging in to accounts in this state, but a local login (like with su) may still be possible.
One possible (non-insecure) use for this would be for an account that had nologin as its shell.

Thanks for the answer - yes. The security point is another main concern. So: Why/When create an account with free access to other users?

never?  For every use of that I can think of, there's a better way to do it.

Why did you write "never?". I don't understand the point of your comment

I thought the rest of that line explained it.  Were there other words on that line you didn't understand?  Not sure how to answer.
